# Draw a circle path in google map static api

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2, google-maps-static-api

I am developing an app using map static api in android

this is the business logic, get user location request from google static api with this location and draw a circle around this location

this is the code I am using

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=29.31166,47.481766&zoom=7&size=600x300&maptype=roadmap&key=My Key
```

the problem now how to draw a circle around it, I searched and I found it is done using path, but could not understand how to get that path

Answer (score 6):

You need just draw path as in [Developers Guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/dev-guide#Paths):

`http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=29.31166,47.48177&zoom=7&size=600x300&path=color:0x0000FFFF|weight:3|fillcolor:0x0000FF77|<FIRST_POINT_LAT>,<FIRST_POINT_LNG>|<SECOND_POINT_LAT>,<SECOND_POINT_LNG>|...|<LAST_POINT_LAT>,<LAST_POINT_LNG>&key=<YOUR_API_KEY>`

where `<FIRST_POINT_LAT>,<FIRST_POINT_LNG>|<SECOND_POINT_LAT>,<SECOND_POINT_LNG>|...|<LAST_POINT_LAT>,<LAST_POINT_LNG>` is coordinates of your circle path. For it's calculation you can use method like that:

```
private List<LatLng> getCirclePoints(LatLng center, double radius) {
    List<LatLng> circlePoints = new ArrayList<>();

    // convert center coordinates to radians
    double lat_rad = Math.toRadians(center.latitude);
    double lon_rad = Math.toRadians(center.longitude);
    double dist = radius / 6378137;

    // calculate circle path point for each 5 degrees
    for (int deg = 0; deg < 360; deg += 5) {
        double rad = Math.toRadians(deg);

        // calculate coordinates of next circle path point
        double new_lat = Math.asin(Math.sin(lat_rad) * Math.cos(dist) + Math.cos(lat_rad) * Math.sin(dist) * Math.cos(rad));
        double new_lon = lon_rad + Math.atan2(Math.sin(rad) * Math.sin(dist) * Math.cos(lat_rad), Math.cos(dist)
                - Math.sin(lat_rad) * Math.sin(new_lat));

        // convert new lat and lon to degrees
        double new_lat_deg = Math.toDegrees(new_lat);
        double new_lon_deg = Math.toDegrees(new_lon);

        circlePoints.add(new LatLng(new_lat_deg, new_lon_deg));
    }

    return circlePoints;
}
```

And you can format Static Maps API URL with that points this way:

```
private String buildStaticApiUrlWithCircle(LatLng mapCenter, int zoom, int width, int height,
                                           LatLng circleCenter, double circleRadius, int pathWeight, String pathColor, String fillColor) {

    List<LatLng> circlePoints =getCirclePoints(circleCenter, circleRadius);

    StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder();
    url.append("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?");
    url.append(String.format("center=%8.5f,%8.5f", mapCenter.latitude, mapCenter.longitude));
    url.append(String.format("&zoom=%d", zoom));
    url.append(String.format("&size=%dx%d", width, height));

    // set circle path properties
    url.append(String.format("&path="));
    url.append(String.format("color:%s", pathColor));
    url.append(String.format("|weight:%d", pathWeight));
    url.append(String.format("|fillcolor:%s", fillColor));

    // add circle path points
    for (LatLng point : circlePoints) {
        url.append(String.format("|%8.5f,%8.5f", point.latitude, point.longitude));
    }

    // add API key to URL
    url.append(String.format("&key=%s", <YOUR_API_KEY>)));
    return url.toString();
}
```

Circle path and fill colours should be set as `String` in `"0xRRGGBBAA"` format, where `RR` - value of red channel, `GG` - value of green channel, `BB` - value of blue channel and `AA` - value of alpha channel (e.g. `"0x0000FFFF"` - pure blue with no transparency, `"0xFF000077"` - pure red 50% transparent and so on).

When you use `buildStaticApiUrlWithCircle()` this way:

```
...
int mapZoom = 7;
int mapWidth = 600;
int mapHeight = 300;
LatLng mapCenter = new LatLng(29.31166, 47.481766);

LatLng circleCenter = new LatLng(29.376297, 47.976379);
double circleRadiusMerers = 35000;
String circlePathColor = "0x0000FFFF";
String circleFillColor = "0x0000FF99";

String mapUrl = buildStaticApiUrlWithCircle(mapCenter, mapZoom, mapWidth, mapHeight,
                                            circleCenter, circleRadiusMerers, 3, circlePathColor, circleFillColor);

try {
    Bitmap mapBitmap = new GetStaticMapAsyncTask().execute(mapUrl).get();
    mMapImageView.setImageBitmap(mapBitmap);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ExecutionException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
...
```

where `GetStaticMapAsyncTask` is:

```
private class GetStaticMapAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {

        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.connect();

            int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();

            InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
        }

        return bitmap;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

    }
}
```

you'll got something like that:

[image: Static map with circle path]

Also, you can use [Google Maps Lite Mode](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/lite) instead of Static Map API (Lite Mode supports drawing circles). Or even, if you need draw circle exactly at the center of the map - direct drawing on bitmap canvas. For example you can modify `doInBackground()` of `GetStaticMapAsyncTask` this way:

```
protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {

    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;

    try {
        URL url = new URL(params[0]);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.connect();

        int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap mapBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);

        Paint locaionMarkerPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        locaionMarkerPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);

        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mapBitmap.getWidth(), mapBitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        canvas.drawBitmap(mapBitmap,0,0, null);
        canvas.drawCircle(mapBitmap.getWidth()/ 2, mapBitmap.getHeight() / 2, 20, locaionMarkerPaint);

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (connection != null) {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
    }

    return bitmap;
}
```

Comment: this seem to be a good solution, I did not try it, I used a static image and put it as mask to my map, but your solution encourage me to try it, Will try it and get back to you